# Proof or disproof that for composite $n$, $(2^n)-1$ is also composite

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

While trying to solve a problem my friend asked me, "is $(2^{50})-1$ prime?", I found a pattern where if $n$ is composite, $(2^n)-1$ is also composite, and in many cases if $n$ is prime, the term is also prime. However this fails at a few prime numbers, the first of which is $11$. I was able to check for composite results up to $80$ before having to work on other things. I am wondering if anybody can prove or disprove the assertion above. While playing around with the pattern, I also found that for composite $n$, $(a^n)-(a-1)$ is also composite. I am less sure about this one, but it is much more exciting if true.

Comment: This has been explained on our site so many times that I have lost count. The duplicate target I picked is a generalization - study its answers. It came up when I searched for the most highly voted posts fitting certain key buzzwords.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right. I am going to delete my answer.

Comment: What is "a" in your second claim ? An arbitary base ?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking at the so-called Mersenne numbers $M_1, M_2, \ldots$. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html.

In order for $M_n$ to be prime, $n$ must be prime. The Mersenne numbers that are prime are called *Mersenne primes*. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersennePrime.html for more.